# How to create a dummy variable stating if two values match in 30 similar variables in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm not sure how to ask this question.
I have a dataset that looks something like this.

| ID | B1L1Kod | B2L3Kod | B1L2Kod | B30L1Kod | B1L1par | B2L3par | B1L2par | B30L1par |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | NA | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | NA | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 39 | 59 | 39 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 39 | 59 | 39 |

I want to write a command in R that returns a new dummy variable with the value of 1 if B1L1Kod match a specific value and B1L1par match another specific value.

I have tried the following code

```
mutate(´newdummy = case_when(B1L1Kod == '5' & B1L1par == '69' ~ '1', TRUE ~ '0'))
```

However, I want to not have to rewrite the code for all possible combinations of variable namnes. Instead I want the command to match so that if the first four digits (B1L1, B2L3, etc) are the same for each pair so to say, and if the specific values match, then newdummy will return the value of 1. In the same dataset I also have other variables starting with B1L1 so the command need to only focus on the combination of XXXXKod and XXXXpar.

Suggestions?

I am totally lost, so I have not tried anything except repeating the command above and changing the digits.

/

Comment: are the values in the table numeric or characters?

Comment: They are both numeric and characthers.

Comment: The command that I have written works. The issue is that it only calls on two variables, and I have 30-ish lookalike variables that I want to address.

Comment: Can we assume that for every existing "radix" (the first four characters of the name) you have both the Kod and par columns?

Comment: Yes. Every kod and par comes in a combination. So B1L1, B1L2 and so on.

Comment: Are you always checking for the values of 5 and 69? Or do those change by column prefix?

Comment: I feel like an ugly hack, but sometimes I use excel to generate big chunks of repetitive text for code.  I can show you how to do it, it should take 5 minutes to do, and it can do the job in writing your tidyverse code.

Comment: I always check for the same values. Then, of course, I will use the command to create other dummies checking for other values.

Comment: When you say "check for the same values" do you mean `x == y` (ie, x and y are the *same values*) or do you mean `x == 1` and `y == 2` (ie, x and y always equal the *same constant*)?

Comment: The second one, x == 1, y == 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require(stringr)
commoncols<-intersect(str_replace(grep("Kod$", names(df), value = TRUE), "Kod$", ""), 
                      str_replace(grep("par$", names(df), value = TRUE), "par$", ""))
kodcols<-paste0(commoncols, "Kod")
parcols<-paste0(commoncols, "par")
df$dummy<-Reduce("|", Map(\(x,y) df[[x]]=="69" & df[[y]]=="5", kodcols, parcols))
```

**Data**

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), B1L1Kod = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), B2L3Kod = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), B1L2Kod = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), B30L1Kod = c(8L, NA, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), B1L1par = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, NA, 9L, 9L), B2L3par = c(94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 39L, 39L
), B1L2par = c(29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 59L, 59L), B30L1par = c(69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 39L, 39L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Almost what I wanted. However, I want one dummy stating if any of the cases are true.

Comment: Ok, I made an edit

Comment: Now it seems to works! Thanks!

Comment: Tried to expand the command, but it doesn't seem to work, see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

We can write a little helper function to make the comparison easier

```
find_pair <- function(a, b) {
  function(x) {
    x == a & pick(gsub("Kod$", "par", cur_column()))[[1]]==b
  }
}
```

This will only work in an `across()` context, but we get the current value and then use `gsub` to get the name of the "paired" variable. We can then compare them to the desired values. We would use it like

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("Kod"), find_pair("5","69"), .names="{.col}_dummy"))
```

Tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="ID   B1L1Kod B2L3Kod B1L2Kod B30L1Kod    B1L1par B2L3par B1L2par B30L1par
                 1  5   6   7   8   9   94  29  69
                 1  5   6   7   NA  9   94  29  69
                 1  5   6   7   8   9   94  29  69
                 1  5   6   7   8   NA  94  29  69
                 2  6   7   8   9   9   39  59  39
                 2  6   7   8   9   9   39  59  39", header=T)
```

Comment: Tried the code, but it returns this info.
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(ends_with("Kod"), find_pair("19410967", "035"), .names = "{.col}_dummy")`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `Paf1_Kod_dummy`.
Caused by error in `pick()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Paf1_par` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: It worked with the test data. Your error message seems to reference columns not in the sample. I guess I’m not sure what your actual data looks like. Did you test it with the sample data I put in my answer?

Comment: It worked with the test data but not with the actual dataset. The error seems to come from the find_pair function

Comment: I think the issue is that I have variables named Paf1_Kod that do not have a pair (Paf1_par).

Comment: You could flip it so it looks for all _par fields and then looks for the _Kod files. But you need a valid starting point. If the values aren't balanced, you'd need to add in another step to actually find which columns are paired.

Answer (score 0):

One approach in base R is to use `sapply` across the column prefixes you want:

```
prefixes <- unique(gsub("Kod$|Kap$|par$|mon$", "", names(data)))
prefixes <- prefixes[!grepl("ID", prefixes)]

data[paste0(prefixes, "_indicator")] <- sapply(prefixes, \(x){
  xx <- data[,grep(x, names(data))]
  ifelse(xx[,1] %in% "5" & xx[,2] %in% "69", 1, 0)
})
```

Output:

```
  ID B1L1Kod B2L3Kod B1L2Kod B30L1Kod B1L1par B2L3par B1L2par B30L1par B1L1_indicator B2L3_indicator B1L2_indicator B30L1_indicator
1  1       5       6       7        8       9      94      29       69              0              0              0               0
2  1       5       6       7       NA       9      94      29       69              0              0              0               0
3  1       5       6       7        8       9      94      29       69              0              0              0               0
4  1       5       6       7        8      NA      94      29       69              0              0              0               0
5  2       6       7       8        9       9      39      59       39              0              0              0               0
6  2       6       7       8        9       9      39      59       39              0              0              0               0
>
```

Note: using `%in%` here instead of `==` will assume that if a value in either column has `NA`, it is *not* the desired value so will return 0. If you want to return `NA` if there is an `NA` in either column, replace `%in%` with `==`.

Answer (score -2):

This is an ugly hack.  ... but it works... quickly if not pretty.

So I use excel to generate code for other languages.  I just wire text expressions across.

Lets say the input variable names and target values are in columns like this:
[image]

Then I can set up text code to make the cases with "glue", in this case the "&" symbol.  I manually remove the character at the end element of the list.

Here is the output column that I would insert interior to the case expression.
[image]

Here it is in excel code-view:
[image]

And here is the ascii for the first code block:
="("&D5&" == "& E5 &") & "

If I had upper and lower bounds, or excluded cases it would be pretty straightforward to wire them in similarly.